# How to filter a JQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-filter

I have created a dialogue and stored it in a variable. Later on I want to run some JQuery on this object, but I can't get it to work.

Here is an example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxKielland/YAuG3/) to try out, or check the example here:

```
var Dialog = $('<div title="Form"><p>Foo foo, bar foo bar bar.</p><input type="checkbox" id="foo"/><label for="foo">foo</label><input type="checkbox" id="bar"/><label for="bar">bar</label></div>').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false
});
$(Dialog).filter("input").button();
$(Dialog).dialog("open");
```

I want to run `.button()` on all input element in the `Dialog` variable befor I open the dialog. The result I get now is what you would expect if you didn't apply `.button()` at all.

If i try `$(Dialog).filter("div")` in the consol I get the div element, but if I try anything within the div, such as p or label I get nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) because you are looking for a descendant element, [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is used to reduce the matching set to a subset which satisfies the given criteria.

```
$(Dialog).find("input")
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jQhXw/)

Comment: Dooh!! Filter, Find sounds similar ;)